# Angular2 - Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 2, without prior experience of Angular.
I was following this tutorial: https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/03/25/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-1-your-first-component/.

And after adding new component "app-people-list" and updating the same in index.html, i get below exception. What went wrong?

```
    Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2808)
    at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.es5.js:13710)
    at createElement (core.es5.js:9259)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12225)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12154)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13535)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12852)
    at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9945)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4822) Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:70399:19)
    at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:57800:49)
    at createElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53349:23)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:56315:44)
    at createRootView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:56244:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:57625:42)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:56942:12)
    at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54035:46)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47423:29)
    at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48912:57)
api.onUnhandledError @ zone.js:643
handleUnhandledRejection @ zone.js:667
_loop_1 @ zone.js:658
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:662
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:592
zone.js:645 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2808)
    at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.es5.js:13710)
    at createElement (core.es5.js:9259)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12225)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12154)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13535)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12852)
    at 

    ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9945)
        at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
        at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4822)
        at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2808)
        at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.es5.js:13710)
        at createElement (core.es5.js:9259)
        at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12225)
        at createRootView (core.es5.js:12154)
        at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13535)
        at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12852)
        at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9945)
        at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
        at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4822)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:770)
        at zone.js:696
        at zone.js:712
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
        at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:141)
        at zone.js:818
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
        at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
        at <anonymous>
```

All the code is exactly as per the tutorial link above. But i am still adding some details below.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calui</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-people-list></app-people-list>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to app!!');
  }));
});
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PeopleListComponent } from './people-list/people-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, PeopleListComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

people-list.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PeopleListComponent } from './people-list.component';

describe('PeopleListComponent', () => {
  let component: PeopleListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PeopleListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PeopleListComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PeopleListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

people-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  template: `
    <p>
      people-list Works!
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css']
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: You probably did not change the `selector` property, instead changed the component name or something. Post your component code.

Comment: upload/post your code

Comment: Can you post your code for index.html and Appcomponent (mian component getting bootstrapped or app-people-list component)

Comment: @skeptor please find the updated question, it contains the details you guys were asking for. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In app.module.ts , `bootstrap` is still pointing to `AppComponent` change it to `PeopleListComponent`

Comment: @Skeptor Yes by changing the bootstrap to PeopleListComponent, peoplelist now works.
But i wanted to use both app-root and app-people-list at the same time, and i am unable to use app-root anymore because I removed it from bootstrap.
How to get both working at the same time(for example in index.html I would like to use app-root and ap-peoplelist at the same time)?
Also as in example https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule, the bootstrap always contains "AppComponent", even though it has other declarations.

Comment: Then revert back the bootstrap . Add `<app-people-list>` tag to `app.component.html`

Comment: @Skeptor, you are right, it works as expected. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Skeptor, not sure if i can vote a comment as answer, instead can you please add an answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Will write answer . Glad I could help

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Angular starts with a root component. When you give

```
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

in your `app.modules.ts`, angular searches for first instance of `app-root` in your HTML and replaces that tag with angular application.
So, your AppComponent `selector` should match to the root component in HTML .

You need to add other component code *inside* `app.component.html` , so that angular can display them . It follows `tree` structure where `app-root` is at the top .

Comment: I am using angular 6, I had to move my scripts at the end of body element. Using Angular 6 with Asp.Net MVC

Comment: @Faisal, that should not be the case . You can create a new question giving your problem and how you solved it and asking if its the right way , what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

one of the simple way sometimes is just to create a new project (definitely only feasible if you are working on a basic project) - there are cases where you might have missed something - this way you can save some good time and focus on learning. This was my experience wasted almost 5 hours finding the reason why this didnt work and I was able to see output by just recreating the entire thing using basic start commands and code changes again on a new boilerplate.

Answer (score 4):

This also happens when your javascript tag is not closed

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if `<script>` tag is put before the `<app-root>` itself. Thanks for the very clear error message Angular!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had included angular project2's dist content into angular project1's assets dir and I was trying to access it from `http://localhost:4200/assets/project2/index.html`. Bu Having an iframe inside project1's component.

project1 was created with `ng new project1 --prefix project1`
project2 was created with `ng new project2 --prefix project2`.

I was getting `Error: The selector "project1-root" did not match any elements`.

Not an elegant way to handle 2 angular projects, but I wanted something quick to test, and it didn't work. I ended up including project2 as a separate module in project1.

*Guess, listening to elders (to KISS) is a good thing* =)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, `index.html` was empty, but I had other files such as `brand-1.index.html` and `brand-2.index.html` etc. In `angular.json` there was a `file-replacement` on `index.html`. This meant I needed to include `--configuration=brand-1` or `build:ssr:brand-1` somewhere in the build pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is keep  in index.html  and in app.component.html  and in app-routing.modile.ts, you can put your component i.e.  as the default page when the application loads.It's coming error because i haven't created the component as well as have not imported it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old query.
Still, check if you have missed "" in your app.component.html or default component html file.

If not present, then do add this router-outlet. Hope this will work out.