# Correct angular 6 architecture in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, architecture, angular6

I have an existing .NET Framework application: ASP.NET MVC (4.6.1). It contains the typical controllers and `.cshtml` views.

Now we are going to introduce angular 6 (before we had angularjs on a small amount of pages). So I am wondering what the best use is of angular's modular architecture without having to re-work every view at this point.

Ideally (in angular's / front-end perspective), your application is fully routed through angular and don't have any `cshtml` anymore as only some `Home.cshtml` that loads the angular-application.

But due the size of the application and the amount of work it would require to re-work everything, I am trying to find the best way to combine both technologies (which could also have some benefits?) and slowly move pages to angular 6 one by one.

That also brings me to the point that it would be beneficial to only load the components/modules I would really need in that certain page. So for example, when showing an index page I don't need details components. This to reduce the load time of the angular-application itself within every page.

So far of my understanding: Every module that is created, can only have one bootstrap component. Meaning, I would need to create a module for every `cshtml` page?

With that knowledge, I came up with the following architecture:

[image]

So this is for 1 'section' in the application. Wherever a new section requires functionalities that can be done with angular I would be doing the same thing. In this way routing is done by MVC and not within the angular components.

Am I on the right path? Is this the best way to go? Or am I missing something crucial that would perform much better?

Now I am wondering: how do I correctly re-structure the `main.ts` which for now contains:

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { ContactplanListModule } from './app/contactplan/contactplan-list/contactplan-list.module';
import { ContactplanDetailsModule } from './app/contactplan/contactplan-details/contactplan-details.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanListModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanDetailsModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Of course this would now just load all modules when I include `dist/main.js`. Which is fine in the beginning but I am wondering if this can easily be split apart.

I have thought of doing something like this, I actually just ran across this because it was complaining that the other 2 modules [were not in the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625753/2901207). It does work but I guess everything is still combined in the same `.js` file?

```
if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/index") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().endsWith("contactplans")) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanListModule)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
} else if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("Contactplans/details") || window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes("contactplans/create")) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContactplanDetailsModule)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
} else {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

}
```

I have looked into lazy loading but for that I would have to use routing throughout the entire application, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ASP.NET, however, I think that your question is not specific to the actual back-end technology.

As you may have already realized, every time you route from a "page" served by your ASP.NET application to an Angular "page", you will be bootstrapping the Angular application, and every time you route from the Angular application to an ASP.NET page, the Angular application will be unloaded.

That said, probably the best way to handle this is to create what is commonly referred to as a "shell" Angular application - one that loads only the root module, with a router.
Then, you create one module per logical "page", and make all of those modules lazily loaded.

In this way, every time you route from ASP.NET to Angular, a very small root module is loaded and bootstrapped, and then depending on the route, a single 'feature module' corresponding to the logical "page" is loaded, and all of the other modules are not loaded (unless you subsequently route to them).

By setting up the router to dynamically (lazy) load all "page" modules, you can get rid of all of the bootstrapping code that you have in your question. Angular will do all of this for you by setting the routes to the modules as lazy.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I do not quite get how this would work. How would the shell application know which "angular-page" (component/module) to route to when I change the page within ASP.NET. For example going from /index to /details (asp.net routed). How do I configure angular so that it loads a details module on the /details page. (so far I know, angular-routing doesn't know of this ASP.NET path).

Comment: "a very small root module is loaded and bootstrapped, and then depending on the route, a single 'feature module' corresponding to the logical "page" is loaded", does that mean that angular somehow keeps track of what actual URL is being shown and then load whatever module? I would love to see a code example of this.

Comment: It doesn't keep track of the url per se, rather you access the application with a route that points to the module. When the app's main module loads, it inspects the url, matches it to the route & the route loads the lazy module. 

The example at https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules shows how it's done in general, but does not lazy load everything. But it explains the general design issues. 

I also just realized that what other folks are referring to as the "app shell" pattern does this, but also tends to include server-side rendering for and client-side caching for the "shell"