# Static html pages with angular 6

Tags: html, typescript, angular6, angular-cli-v6

## Problem

I have 4 static pages with full angular 6 web app I want to render home.html page on start and after login redirect to actual angular web app from where angular routing fired up and do the magic. question is why I want this? I want this because my web app have some static pages like home, contact us,I want  terms and conditions and privacy policy etc. I want this pages to be static for crawler friendly and also for fast rendering by excluding angular out of it.

## Question

How I can achieve this.

## Done so far

I create 3 static pages in root where index.html is located. the in angular cli I put this line

```
"index": "src/home.html",
```

but now I an unable to navigate to contactus.html page it shows me this error.

## Error

```
"The selector "app-root" did not match any elements"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625753/2134604

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can use "Routes" for mapping your page and show in the same "index" all your contend easily. Is versatile, because with that, you can manage lot of things like the session access: I show you an example:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
/*Example component*/
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';
import{ ExamplePage } from './page1/examplePage.component';
/*Routes mapping*/
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: '', component: InicioComponent },
 {path: 'proveedores', component: ExamplePage, canActivate: [GuardService] }] /* Example of protected by session page*/
@NgModule({
declarations: [
ExamplePage,
InicioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
]
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <router-outlet>**Here are all the pages**</router-outlet>
    </div>
```

This is only a short example, is complicated do a deep explain of that here, but there are a lot of documentation in angular.io about this module: https://angular.io/guide/router