# why <app-root> is not a known element with out body tag

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am new to this angular 6. This may be stupid to ask but i want to make my concept clear. Below is the code my of appComponent typescript

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from './services/toastr.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers:[ToastrService]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  }
```

when i put `<app-root>` in the index.html in the following format. it works perfectly fine.

```
 <html>

    <body>
            <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when i remove the html and body tags it just give me an error given below.

```
main.ts:12 Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:1073)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:229)
    at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.js:20837)
    at createElement (core.js:17499)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:19737)
    at createRootView (core.js:19690)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:20208)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:18029)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create
```

So my question is.. Do i have to write `<app-root>` alway in html or body tag? or is there any other way to write  `<app-root>`  with out writing in html or body tag?

Thanks

Comment: This would be an interesting opportunity for you to follow the stack trace and dive into the Angular source code to see how it is finding the root element.

Comment: Yeah dude, and I’m saying the source code may answer his question and reveal some interesting tidbits about how else he might do whatever he is trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589738/angular2-error-the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-elements)