# The selector "app-root" did not match any elements after update to Angular 7

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular7

After updating the client app of an ASP.Net Core MVC SPA-project from Angular 5.2 to Angular 7, I receive the following runtime error when loading the app from `index.html`:

> The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

```
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (VM147 vendor.js:76470)
    at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (VM147 vendor.js:67815)
    at createElement (VM147 vendor.js:64501)
    at createViewNodes (VM147 vendor.js:66739)
    at createRootView (VM147 vendor.js:66692)
    at callWithDebugContext (VM147 vendor.js:67700)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (VM147 vendor.js:67210)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (VM147 vendor.js:65031)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (VM147 vendor.js:53458)
    at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap (VM147 vendor.js:61611)
```

The problems seems to be, that the scripts are executed before the DOM is initialized, thus not finding the element. The 'compiled' index.html source looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>capatrello</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</html>
```

The script files are automatically inserted at the start of the file. If I manually insert the scripts at the end of the file, the app starts and works as expected. However, the scripts are then inserted and executed twice, still throwing errors at the first try. The compiled index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>capatrello</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

- By what mechanism are the script files inserted into index.html?
- Can it be configured to insert the script files at the end of index.html?
- Is this a proper fix or is the root cause somewhere else?

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589738/angular2-error-the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-elements

Comment: @mojtabaramezani Iwasnt able to fix it with the post you mentioned. could you elaborate?

Comment: see what's the selector of your main component, it's possible was app-main, not app-root

Comment: @Eliseo The main component selector and tag in index.html match, that's not the issue. As I said in my question, the app works when manually adding the scripts to the bottom, which wouldnt be the case if the selector was wrong.

Comment: @Marc can you remvoe those script tag above html in the top to see if it work ? I wonder why it generate 2 time