# Why is Angular app-root not being detected in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress

I am working on a project that requires Angular to be loaded in a Wordpress plugin, and am running into an error with:

```
main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1 ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at e.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at yi (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at ji (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at Ni (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at Object.Xi [as createRootView] (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at t.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at t.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at e.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

The plugin code:

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Example
* Description: description
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Some guy
* Author URI: www.website.com
* Test Domain: pluginname
*/

wp_register_script( 'example_main5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/main-es5.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_main2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/main-es2015.js', __FILE__));
// wp_register_script( 'example_poly5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/polyfills-es5.js', __FILE__));
// wp_register_script( 'example_poly2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/polyfills-es2015.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_run5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/runtime-es5.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_run2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/runtime-es2015.js', __FILE__));


function example_enqueue_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('example_main5_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_main2015_js');
  // wp_enqueue_script('example_poly5_js');
  // wp_enqueue_script('example_poly2015_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_run5_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_run2015_js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_script');



function example_test_function() {

echo '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HelloApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>';
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'example_test_function');
?>
```

I have consulted with [previous threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589738/angular2-error-the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-elements) on this topic, and everything is properly declared in the selector, etc; The pure Angular version of this works without issue in both production and development environment tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<script>` tag that loads the Angular bundles of JavaScript **must** come after the `<app-root>` element in the HTML. JavaScript is executed once it is loaded and if the rest of the Html hasn't been loaded, then the selector will fail to find `<app-root>`.

If you can not *move* the `<script>` tag, then you can use the `defer` attribute to run the JavaScript after the Html document is read.

```html
<script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Following that logic, I moved the functions to register and enqueue the scripts and to add that particular action until after the echoing out of the HTML code, and that gets rid of the console errors, but the app still isn't rendering, despite the `app-root` clearing being detectable when I inspect the code elements.

Comment: @MichaelC I don't know. If you're not getting any JavaScript errors, then you need to verify that the proper JavaScript files are actually being loaded.

Comment: pointed out what turned out to be my problem; I had (incorrectly) assumed that `wp_enqueue_script` loaded scripts in the footer by default, but it has to be specified in the optional (5th) argument to that function like so: 

wp_enqueue_script('cbd_main5_js', '', [], false, true);